# How to encode datetime as numbers?

Tags: python, datetime, encode

I'm looking for a method to encode DateTime entries like `2017-11-28 11:45:00` in a numerical code containing a number for each month, each business day, including Saturday, the holidays all of them as a unique number, including Sunday, and the hours just as day shift, like morning and afternoon.

Accordingly, the DateTime `2017-11-28 11:45:00` which was November, thirsday, morning would get something like `1121`, where November is 11, Tuesday is 2, and morning is 1.

However, `2017-04-23 14:30:03` which is April, Sunday, afternoon, would get something like 472, where 4 is April, 7 is Sunday, and 2 afternoons. A holiday should be coded just like Monday, but Saturday not. 
Of course, the code format above is just an idea but not mandatory.

I want to use these data as a neural network input so that it is important to know, for my modeling purposes, the specific business day, holidays, day shift and month.

Thanks

Comment: What exact problem do you try to solve with your custom encoding?

Why not just use a tuple or a string with separators. Is it for memory efficiency?


If you explain what you want to do with that data we might potentially give better advice.

Comment: If you want to input it to a NN, wouldn't it make more sense to just have multiple inputs? One indicator variable for business day or not business day. One for day of the week (categorical, not integer) etc. Take a look at how fast AI does it for example: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/03/feature-engineering-dates-fastai.html

Comment: I'm not a neural network expert, just having some basic many years old knowledge, but assume it would be better for  the neural network to provide three separate numbers one for month one for day of week and one for holiday

Comment: Cool @Dan! This link may help me. Just answering your question: the different business days matter for me. :)

Comment: @MarlonTeixeira either way, I don't think you should be trying to encode it all into a single number. Why make like harder for your network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- - - - - - - - - 

Input: date

Process : Main

Output: Format: Month + day + turn




Process:

month = get_month(date)

day_week = get_day(date)

hour = get_your(date)



f_monht = format_month(month)

f_day = format_day(day_week)

f_turn = format_turn(hour)


print f_monht + f_day + f_turn
```

---

```
# ---------import-------------
import datetime

# ----------DEFs--------------
def format_date(date_string):
  d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

  #month = get_month(date)
  month = d.month

  # day_week = get_day(date)
  day_week = d.weekday()

  # hour = get_hour(date)
  hour = d.hour

  f_monht = format_month(month)
  f_day = format_day(day_week)
  f_turn = format_turn(hour)

  return f_monht + f_day+f_turn

def format_month(month):
  return str(month)

def format_day(day_week):
  return str(day_week+1)

def  format_turn(hour):
  if hour < 12:
    return '1'
  elif hour <18:
    return '2'
  else:
    return '3'


#-----------MAIN--------------
date_1 = '2017-11-28 11:45:00'
f_date_1 = format_date(date_1)
print(f_date_1)

date_2 = '2017-04-23 14:30:03'
f_date_2 = format_date(date_2)
print(f_date_2)
```

The source code is large, precisely for educational purposes. Reduce to your discretion